# Withdrawal of the amount of money via Unity Event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

there is a problem with withdrawing the amount of money through Unity Event. Money is updated only for killing demons already on the stage at the time of the game launch, but not updated for killing demens created from the prefab. What could be the reason for this behavior? I attach the code and screenshots. Thank you in advance.

Demon
[image: Image 1]

```
[SerializeField] public UnityEventInt onChangeMoney;
void DeathProcess()
    {
        onChangeMoney.Invoke(deathCost);
        ...
    }
```

PlayerObjectScript
[image: Image 2]

```
[SerializeField] public UnityEventInt onChangeMoney;
public int money;
    public void ChangeMoney(int delta)
    {
        money += delta;
        onChangeMoney.Invoke(money);
    }
```

PlayerMoneyController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMoneyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;


    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void UpdateHandler(int money)
    {
        text.text = money.ToString();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]

P.S. Sorry for my English, translated by a translator

Comment: The objects you referenced in the events as listener are prefabs or the actual instances in your scene? (Spoiler: If it is within the prefab hierarchy itself you can do it in the prefab but otherwise you don't want prefabs but the actual instances from the scene)

Comment: I would also like to add that if the Debug.Log(money) line is entered in the Update Handler, then the amount of money will be correctly output to the console, but the text on the screen does not change

Comment: So you already know that it is most probably the `PlayerMoneyController` that is not listening correctly and most probably where you referenced a prefab instead of an actual instance from the scene

Comment: The thing is that the UpdateHandler in PlayerMoneyController is triggered, as evidenced by the withdrawal of the amount of money to the console. Also, in order to make sure that the link to the text is correct, I added the string text.text = "null" to Start(), and this works, the text on the screen becomes "null" at startup, this confuses me

Comment: again: This only proves that you have a working `PlayerMoneyController` instance in your scene ... it doesn't prove that this is actually the one you have referenced in the Event as listener ... click on the reference in the even and it will highlight the according object ... is it the prefab or the one in the scene? ;) In general start [Debugging your code with breakpoints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

Comment: If you just drag your demon into the scene you'll see that your event reference to the OnChangeMoney in BaseTurret will be broken...

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the reason for this behavior?

It's about references, when you set up your scene, your enemy can have a reference about your turret because both of them exist in the same scene, both are objects that will exist in runtime. But at the moment that you make your enemy a prefab, they will turn into an asset, and an asset can't (at least not without additional effort) know about runtime items, can't ref references to it because they don't have any guarantee that when you drag your enemy into scene your turret will exist and that this turret reference is the same turret that you have set when they exist in hierarchy only. This is the reason why only your objects that exist in the scene will keep the right behavior.

What you need to do is find a way to get turret reference, maybe store it in another place and find it in a setup phase when instantiating new enemies. You can also create an event calling layer that can be a scriptable object, and a scriptable object as prefabs are both assets, so they can safely reference each other. You can also change this event to code only and turn it into a static event. You have many approaches to solve it, good luck